# Read environment variables from file before starting docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have this dockerfile

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.7.12-management
CMD . /files/envinfo && echo $RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER && rabbitmq-server
```

In the envinfo I have this content

export RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER='anothername'

When the docker starts up the echo of RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER really prints out anothername. But when the service starts it doesnt see it.

If I set the environment variable another way from the kubernetes file it works as it should.

You can see the rabbitmq image I extend here.
https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/35b41e318d9d9272126f681be74bcbfd9712d71b/3.8/ubuntu/Dockerfile

I have another process that fetches the file and puts it in /files/envinfo to make it available for this docker image when it starts. So I cant use environment settings from  kubernetes.

Looking forward to hear some suggestions =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @code-gorilla use Kubernetes environment variables. But another way to do it is to source the environment variables before the entry point:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["source /files/envinfo && docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Overriding `CMD` will only change the argument to `ENTRYPOINT`, that's probably why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hi Jokarls thx for contributing. source doesnt work. It works with the "dot" otherwise it wouldnt work to echo out the env variable right after. I need to figure out why its not avvailable later.

Comment: I missed the fact that you were overriding the `CMD` command and not `ENTRYPOINT`. I have updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: ahh ok so the CMD command is forwarded as a parameter to entrypoint. So if I do this
ENTRYPOINT source /files/envinfo && docker-entrypoint.sh
Then the args from cmd are no longer forwarded to docker-entrypoint.sh do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I hardcoded the parameter like this.
ENTRYPOINT source /files/envinfo && docker-entrypoint.sh rabbitmq-server and then it works. But let me know if you know how to forward the cmd. Thx for your help =)

Comment: It could be that the ENTRYPOINT needs to be in *exec* for (array). I updated my answer again, hope it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug it further:

**1) Connect to the container and check if the env variable set within it**

`docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash`

Then in your container:

`echo $RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER`

**2) Use the Kubernetes evironment variable configuration instead of script execution in CMD**

See the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

Note: I suspect that an evironment variable set within the CMD command is not available in all shells of the container, e.g. when you open a new bash within it. This is what the Kubernetes config takes care of.

Comment: I havev updated the question and added this.
I have another process that fetches the file and puts it in /files/envinfo to make it available for this docker image when it starts. So I cant use environment settings from  kubernetes.

Comment: If I bash into my container I cant see the environment variables loaded by the process. But if I echo it out just after I read the file then its there. Its just gone when the rabbitmq service starts up. I thought it had something to do with how both entrypoint and cmd is used.